# Mapping of symbol (say \alpha) to font + char-id (in ams/foobar.pfb)

Tags: fonts

### Update:

Per Yan's suggestion, currently reading: ctan.tug.org/ctan/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf

### Setup

When I type $\alpha$ in LaTeX, this \alpha becomes mapped to some character inside of some foobar.pfb file.

### Question

Where is this mapping stored?

### Context

This is a followup to:
[Generating fonts of all LaTeX math symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56313/generating-fonts-of-all-latex-math-symbols)

I have figured out that:

```
* I want *.pfb, not *.ttfs
* I can load *.pfbs into my Java display code and they work perfectly fine
```

Now, I need a way to map the various defines in ams math to the various characters in the various *.pfb files.

### Elegant Solution

Given that the mapping is likely not in an easily parseable format, is there a way to get TeX to query it for me? I.e. I'm totally happy defining some macro of the form:

\magicmacro{symbol-name}

which then dumps out to output.log which *.pfb file and which character symbol-name maps to.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you are asking about encoding. See ftp://ctan.tug.org/ctan/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf It is difficult to answer things without actually repeating what's there.  The most relevant part is section 1 and references therein

Comment: I believe what I want is either (1) something like the Appendices of that document, except instead of the actual symbol, I want the LaTeX command used to generate the symbol or (2) a *.enc file <-- not so sure about this one.

Answer (score 4):

The mapping from `\alpha` to the glyph is not so easy. Let's first see how `\alpha` is defined in Plain TeX

```
\mathchardef\alpha="010B
```

This means, first of all, that `\alpha` can be used only in math mode. Then TeX interprets the four hexadecimal figures (`"` is the prefix telling TeX that the following number is expressed in its hexadecimal form):

1. `0` means that `\alpha` is to be considered as an ordinary symbol, for spacing in math formulas;
2. `1` means that the glyph will be taken from the math family number 1
3. `0B` means that the glyph is at position `0B` in that font (a TeX font has 256 slots, numbered from `"00` to `"FF`).

Let's see `\sum`, for comparison:

```
\mathchardef\sum="1350
```

`1` is the "operator type", `3` is the math family and 50 is the slot.

TeX maintains up to 16 math families and families from 0 to 3 have a special meaning: from family 0 are drawn the digits (so the font assigned to it should match the document's main font), the letters for function names like "sin" and the uppercase Greek letters; in family 1 we find the math italic letters and the lowercase Greek letters; in family 2 most of the symbols such as `\times` or `\sim`; in family 3 the big operators like `\sum`, `\int` and the extensible delimiters.

LaTeX builds on the same scheme, of course, but adds some layers for easing programming and switching fonts. Its definition of `\alpha` can be found in `fontmath.ltx`:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathord}{letters}{"0B}
```

that is very similar to the previous one: `\mathord` stands for `0`, `letters` is a symbolic name for `1` and `"0B` denotes the same slot. Here's `\sum`:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"50}
```

(`largesymbols` will be translated into `3` and `\mathop` into `1`).

The story doesn't end here. We have to assign fonts to the math families. This is done again in `fontmath.ltx`:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}   {OT1}{cmr} {m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}     {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
```

assign fonts to the main math families described above. When LaTeX is asked to typeset an `\alpha` (so in the `letters` family) it looks for an OML-encoded font in family `cmm`, medium weight and italic shape; so it looks in the definitions in the file `omlcmm.fd` where it finds

```
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}%
     {<5><6><7><8><9>gen*cmmi%
      <10><10.95>cmmi10%
      <12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmmi12%
      }{}
```

that says, roughly, that if the symbol has to be in size 10 it must be in the font `cmmi10`. It's then a job for `pdftex` to get the translation into the `.pfb` file via the `pdftex.map` file where lines such as

```
cmmi10 CMMI10 <cmmi10.pfb
```

are present; the first `cmmi10` means the TeX font, `CMMI10` is its Postscript name and then `cmmi10.pfb` is the actual Postscript font file.

Not for the faint of heart, I'm afraid: it involves many low level concepts from the basis of TeX and hundreds of definitions. But not unmanageable, after all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what I want is:

/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/source/latex/amsfonts/*.dtx

in particular, the DeclareMathSymbol parts